# Handling a dynamic list of TextFields

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, textfield

How to properly handle state in Flutter is somewhat unintuitive, especially when it comes to depending on server-side delivered content.

I receive a list of n objects from an API. I want to display that list using `ListView` and mapping my list to a bunch of `ListTile`s. In each ListTile, I would like to use a TextField, populate that TextField with a default value, as well as being able to handle each textfield individually (Ultimately, I want to store a value for each TextField in storage, and load that value from storage as the fields initial value as well).

But... How would I go about this? I can't just use a single TextEditingController, as I need one per TextField. But when I initialize my Widget for the first time, I don't yet know how many I need, given that my API call will not have returned a result yet. So I would somehow need to add the controllers dynamically in my widget's build method, which however feels extremely unclean as that code would execute every single time my list gets repainted for whatever reason...

What would be the cleanest way to solve this?

Comment: You could use `TextFormField` instead of `TextField` which has `initialValue`. It could be helpful. Check [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)

Comment: @immadisairaj The doc says that these fields also need a controller, in the same way standard TextFields do.

Comment: `TextFormField` has `initialValue` where you can give initial value to the fields, and there is `onChange` or `onEditingComplete` to save into storage.